# Flexible jQuery checkbox disabling per table line

Tags: php, jquery

I'm not conversant with jQuery, so I'm proud I managed to get this working: https://jsfiddle.net/bigjazzz/xvmjLda1/5/ (Clicking the Sick checkbox disables the other inputs.)

However, I was wondering if there was a way to make it more flexible, so that if I click PHOL N/R or Training it will also disable all the other fields. I'm currently running a PHP loop to manually output each set of code for each line, as I've got zero idea how to make it loop through the numbers. Each line has the class "disableX" attached to it.

I have seen the `.parent()` and `.child()` selectors, but I'm spinning my tires trying to think of how to implement it. (The solution is probably simple, to be honest.)

I have looked to see if other people have the same issue, but I can't seem to find a similar situation. If you know of one with an accepted answer, I'd love to get the link to do some more research.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Assign a new class to the 3 checkboxes that you want to have this function apply to. eg 'disableRow'

```
<input type="checkbox" name="phol2" class="disable2 disableRow">
```

(do the same thing to the other 2 checkboxes).

Then adjust the function to use this new class:

```
$('input.disableRow').click(function() {
 //if the checkox is checked, find the ancetor row, then find all of the row's checkboxes
 if($(this).checked){
    $(this).ancestor('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
//and get me checked too
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
}
```

With jQuery, you can use any CSS selector to assign a function to be triggered on an event. The class doesn't have to be used in the CSS.

You could use the 3 individual id attributes, but this is cleaner and more robust (eg if you add a new checkbox).

Comment: I was hoping I could get away from manually specifying the input name, or perhaps specifying a range of names, so as it would be one bit of code for all three checkboxes (Sick, PHOL N/R, Training). If this isn't possible, that's not a problem, just trying to keep my code tidy.

Comment: I've changed the code to use the class as a selector, so it applies to all 3 checkboxes.

Comment: Wouldn't this then activate when ticking say the Security checkbox?

Comment: Yes it would - adjusted again to fix.

Comment: ... It's so simple. Thanks for this! I'll give it a crack soon and let you know how I go. :)